# Is Chrome erroneously enforcing CSP when in report-only mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, content-security-policy

There's a script tag that is being dynamically loaded into the DOM like so,

```
const scriptCode = `
  (function() {
    var APP_ID = "${intercomAppId}";
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/' + APP_ID;var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);};if(document.readyState==='complete'){l();}else if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
  })()
`;

let intercomPolicy;
if (window.trustedTypes) {
  intercomPolicy = window.trustedTypes.createPolicy("Intercom", {
    createHTML: (html) => html,
  });
}

const sanitizedScriptCode =
  intercomPolicy?.createHTML?.(scriptCode) ?? scriptCode;

const script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = sanitizedScriptCode;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Note that the `script`'s script is itself adding a script tag. Although I believe the error is reported on the "outer" `script` because it is not added to the DOM. I was hopeful that the above would be sufficient, but it's not, Chrome refuses to load this script,

```
This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment. An HTMLScriptElement was directly modified and will not be executed.
```

Not sure if related, but the site has CSP in **report only** mode enabled,

```
content-security-policy-report-only: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src https://fonts.googleapis.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'; require-trusted-types-for 'script'; manifest-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'
```

Firefox reports a CSP violation, but still executes the script as expected given it's in report-only mode.

**Is this a bug in Chrome? Why does Chrome refuse to run the script if CSP is report only**?

Chrome error:

[image: chrome-error]

Firefox error (but script still runs):

[image]

Comment: You need to add a `createScript` property on your policy. To just get rid of the error you can assign it a function that just passes the string through (which is not adding any security here!). That is exactly what your current createHTML function does; as it stands you can as well drop trusted types. You are not helping your site's security at all with the code you've shown.

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal reproducer on your issue and if it can be reproduced, place that over at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list.

Comment: First of all 'require-trusted-types-for' is still considered experimental and not a part of either CSP level 2 or 3. It is only implemented on Chromium, so Firefox will naturally ignore it. It could be that you have found a Chromium issue due to the many levels of script addition that may not be treated as report-only all the way down.